# How to override php session expire on Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm new in Android development. Currently i'm working on webview app.

The webview (website) has a session timeout for example 10 minutes. When the session expired, it will redirect to login page. Is that possible, if the android handling/override the session? I don't want the session expire when run on app.

Currently I've tried used CookieManager but it seem doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm currently doing is this:
Get your android app to send the unique device id via post

```
String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        try {
            postData = "deviceId=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainWebView.postUrl(postUrl,postData.getBytes());
```

Then what im doing is at the home page (launched in android app) I check to see if the android id is in the database and belongs to a specific user.

```
//This is just pseudo code actual implementation depends your database and user login setup
if(!isset($_POST["deviceId"]){
    //no deviceId sent
    //so redirect to login page
}
//check database for deviceId and see if it has a user id associated with  it
if(deviceId has a userID){
    //load user info / log the user in
}
```

And then your user never has to log in on his phone again unless you put some additional logic in to remember the first time they logged in on the app and have it expire a week later.